# How can I send email to user that is not logged in since 30 days?

Tags: 7, emails

I am using Drupal 7, and I want to send email to registered users who have not logged in to the site since 30 days; for example, an email saying:

> Hello user, you are not login since 30 days.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to do this.

Make a rule that that is triggered when a user logs in. Make this rule [schedule](http://drupal.org/node/1582254) sending this e-mail in 30 days. Let the [identifier of the task](http://drupal.org/node/1582442) be something like `30-days reminder for [account:uid]`. This way, if the user logs in within the next 30 days, the scheduled task will be overwritten - pushing the 30 days e-mail.

Make sure to activate the Rules Scheduler module.

Comment: This series of video screencasts on Rules scheduler explains this in more detail: http://nodeone.se/sv/node/770

Comment: @PatrickKenny : be aware, this link is broken. Can you think of a replacement of it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens https://drupalize.me/videos/introducing-rules-scheduler?p=1157

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [User Stats](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) module, it might be something that could work for you. From the module's project page:

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and Views integration. Statistics are:
>
> - Days registered
> - Join date Days since last login
> - Days since last post

etc and then, you can use cronjob to send email.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the *Inactive user* module:

[**Inactive user**

http://drupal.org/project/inactive_user](http://drupal.org/project/inactive_user)

> The inactive_user module provides Drupal administrators with a way to
>   automatically manage inactive user accounts. This module has two
>   goals: to help keep users coming back to your site by reminding them
>   when they've been away for a configurable period of time, and to
>   cleanup unused accounts.

Comment: Inactive_user has 0 documentation, and does nothing.

Comment: inactive_user is unmaintained and has some serious bugs (like sending notifications to blocked users)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to implement hook_cron. like this:

```
function yourmodulename_cron() {
  $users = database query to get users that have not logged on in the last 30 days
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('send_maillast30days');
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $queue->createItem($user);
  }
}
```

Also you will have to implement a queue using hook_cron_queue_info as shown here:

```
function yourmodulename_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['send_maillast30days'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'yourmodulename_send_email30days',
    'time' => 60,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

you will also have to implement "yourmodulename_send_email30days" function: i.e

```
function yourmodulename_send_email30days($user) {
  //use drupal_mail function to send the mail (see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)
}
```