# How do I send an email to users who have been inactive for 30 days with a condition

Tags: entities, rules

I used the answer in [How can I send email to user that is not logged in since 30 days?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60785/how-can-i-send-email-to-user-that-is-not-logged-in-since-30-days) to successfully set up an action set component that would email the user and a rule that would schedule that component delayed by 30 days. It's doing everything I want to except for one thing.

If the user has completed the course (course module) I don't want to nag them about being inactive. However, it doesn't look like I have access to that information when the action set gets evaluated.

The course module has some custom events and the information about course completion is exposed to rules via entities. If I create a rule triggered on the course_updated event I have access to the completion data I need (like this one https://www.drupal.org/node/2151827), but when the event is simply user login or it's triggered by the scheduler, I don't have access to that entity.

Do I need to add a custom condition or can I somehow query the course_report entity for the user who is scheduled?

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to combine both.

Steps:
1. As mentioned in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/60797/10157, you have to use rules+ rules scheduler to add user login condition. 
2. Add the condition for course complete as mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/2151827 to the same rule.