# Have a Rules condition that will take the current time minus last comment posted time

Tags: 7, rules, comments

**Overall goal:**  If a node has not been commented on in a given time frame, send an email.

**How it could possibly be done:**  Have [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) look at the last time a comment was posted when cron runs.  Then do a data comparison of that unit (current time - last comment posted time) to see if its greater than the time frame assigned to the node (ex: hours).  If so, send email.

Is this approach correct?  I am struggling to get the Rule to work if it is.

Comment: is the given time frame, ie: check every 20 min, or is it a 1 time thing, ie: after 2 days?

Comment: Checking every 20 minutes

Comment: is this only for nodes with 0 comments, or if node has 1 comment and 20 min passed and no new comments have been made, still send e-mail?

Comment: Yes if a node has any number of comments and 20 minutes has pass with no additional comments, send email.

Comment: The approach seems right. Are you using the scheduling system included with Rules? I would suggest you read the documentation (https://www.drupal.org/node/1300068)  , as it has a few twists. Another thing to keep in mind is that these rules will run when Cron runs. If you are using the default Drupal Cron ("poorman" Cron or " lazy" Cron), it may end up running at irregular intervals, as it only runs if a visitor visits your site. There are ways to schedule Cron to run on more accurate terms - many online articles about this.

Comment: to follow on @argiepiano comment, you could use [Ultimate Cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

Comment: to follow @No Sssweat comment, for an accurate cron that runs independent of site visits I prefer the module Elysia Cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Overall goal:**  If a node has not been commented on in an in a given time frame, send an email.

Here is a bare bones solution. On paper this should work.

Basically, we use sticky as the tell tell sign if a new comment has been added (if it's not sticky, no one has commented). Once the e-mail gets sent, we set node to unsticky.

1) Create a rule after **saving new comment**.

- Add Action: Under Node, **Make Content Sticky** >> **comment:node**

> Then it's very similar to my answer to your question [Rules Conditions
>   being evaluated after schedule time
>   elapsed?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182928/rules-conditions-being-evaluated-after-schedule-time-elapsed)
>
> ### Create a New Component
>
> 1) Add Compotent of Rule.
>
> 2) For Data Type: select Node. Name, Label and Machine name use
>   whatever you want.
>
> 3) Add condition of **Content is of type**
>
> - For Data Selector: put your Node Data Type machine name. Ex: if you gave the node data type a machine name of `test` you put `test`
> - Select your content type

4) Download and Install [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) Module

Then for action, click on Add IF >> DATA COMPARISON >> test:sticky >> False

Then **in IF: Data Comparison row** click Add Action >> Send Mail

Then in Conditional row (1st row white) you will now see an Else button, click on it.

Then in Else click on Add Action >> Make Content Unsticky >> test

[image]

> ### Now Create a new Rule
>
> 1) For action use after content is created
>
> 2) Leave the condition empty (no need for condition here)
>
> 3) for Action add the scheduled component evaluation and select the
>   component you just created.
>
> - use `node` as your data selector

Comment: I was thinking the Rule would react on "Cron Maintenance" but I've never worked on this sticky functionality so I'll give it a try!

Comment: holdon, we need to reset the sticky for when step 4 is sticky (true)...

Comment: I've never used [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, but if you're able to Make Content Unsticky when step 4 is true then this will work.

Comment: The idea behind this is great.  I am running into minor issues (or bugs) on how to get the nodes unstickied after an amount of time via the scheduler.    I separated out all the Rules to isolate this problem [here](http://i.imgur.com/s8j8eG5.png).  So a look inside the relevant Rule is [here](http://i.imgur.com/zHdmn9t.png).  Then a look inside the scheduled component [here](http://i.imgur.com/h7CPNji.png).  I am not sure where I am going wrong with being able to schedule a node to become unsticky.

Comment: @KyleRiggen as I mentioned in my comments above, you need to download the Conditional Rules module. I was gonna let you figure this part out. Anyways, I have installed it to see how it works and updated Step #4.

Comment: Great so this appears to work with one evaluation time (input from the scheduler) rather than evaluation for the life of the node.  Thank you for getting me this far @No Sssweat!