# How to send an eMail notification when a specific field of a node or user has been changed?

Tags: nodes, entities, rules, emails

When a node (or user profile) is modified, is it possible to send an email notification only when a specified field is modified?

With the node I have no problem, but I cannot get it to work for a specific field.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. Here are some details about how to do so:

- **Rules Event**: Before saving content.
- **Rules Condition**: Compare the value of the specific field, for both the original value (before editing the field) and the (new) updated value, to verify if they are different.
- **Rules Condition**: Send an eMail (which is typically implemented as a separate "Rules Component" (that is invoked as the Rules Action), whereas you pass the values like node id, current user, maybe author, etc. Within the Rules Component, you then compose the actual eMail (template) that you want to be eMailed. For an example of such a Rules component, have a look at my answer to "[How can I set a reminder for a specific user to be triggered on a specific date?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-set-a-reminder-for-a-specific-user-to-be-triggered-on-a-specific-date/166883#166883)" (which includes such component in Rules export format also).

Should be straight forward to "develop" such rule, no (PHP) coding at all involved (only site building using admin UI).

Comment: Great @Pierre.Vriens , seems work as I expected but there is only two little issue:

**i)** compare the body ([node-unchanged:body] with [node:body] ) not works. I receive a notification also if I not changed the text in the body.

**ii)** with field collection the rule not works always as expected ([node:field-myfieldcolletion]). If I "Add another item" the compare works and I receive an email, instead if I edit an existing item (a field of the field collection) the comparison does not work.

Comment: Are you using a rules condition like "entity has field" (for those specific fields)? If not then their values will be process like blank or something.

Comment: Not but I not understand how it works. In "entity has field" I added "node" in "Entity" and "body" in "Field" but the problem persists. PS: in data selector I can't use "node:body:"

Comment: Add some screen: http://i64.tinypic.com/zybipz.jpg and http://oi63.tinypic.com/2u57sdi.jpg

Comment: For "Body" I have solved not with "entity has field" but adding the condition "AND" and after  "NOT Text comparison" with "Parameter: Text: [node:body:value], Matching text: [node-unchanged:body:value]" (http://i64.tinypic.com/a4ydzn.jpg). For the field collection instead the problem persist. If I edit an existing field collection item (a field of the field collection) the comparison seems not work.

Comment: I looked at your newest screenprints you added. It's pretty tough to debug what the remaining issue is. But it MIGHT be that you have that "AND" in the wrong place: Could it be that you should MOVE (drag) the AND above the first condition (that AND expects at least 2 conditions below itself). If that's not the issue, can you then EDIT your question by adding an export of your entire rule you have so far to the end of your question (with something like "this is what I have as a rule so far after trying one of the answers, but it still fails like so and so ..."?

Comment: For the field collection I think I've solved. In **Rules Event** I must simply choose _Before saving a field collection item_. Stay tuned, I'm trying.

Comment: I have big problem with field collection item.
If in *Rule Event*  I choose _Before saving a field collection item_ I can compare the field of field collection but for example if I change four fields, I receive four notifies. Besides in *Rules Condition* the toke [node:title] not work. I can choose only [site:] and [field-collection-item:]. How I can solve it?I'm going crazy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [hook_user_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7).  This hook is called when a user account (user profile?) is updated.

You might also want to look at [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7).  You will not be able to use the `hook_node_update` to be notified when your user accounts are updated, but on this page there is a comment about `$node->original` having the values of the `$node` before the update.

I have not tested this myself (should be a trivial excursive), but you may be lucky and find $account->original (or something similar) stores the original values of the user account.

It is then a simple matter of testing the old field value against the new one to see if a change occurred, and you can take appropriate action - like sending a mail.