# How do I postpone an already postponed deletion

Tags: rules

I made a site in which users can publish content and also postpone the deletion time. Now I want the users to be able to postpone a deletion that have been already been postponed. So I want to consider the remaining time do so.

How can reach this goal?

Answer (score 0):

First an educated (wild) guess ... Since Drupal, out-of-the-box, does not come with some "postpone" facility, I'm going to assume that you implemented that by using the Rules Scheduler to schedule the execution of a Rules Component, which does nothing but delete some content (node).

Have a look at my answer to the question "[How can I set a reminder for a specific user to be triggered on a specific date?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-set-a-reminder-for-a-specific-user-to-be-triggered-on-a-specific-date/166883#166883)". Obviously, that is not the same question as yours here. But the "specific date" there appears to correspond to your "postponed date".

With that, you could just trigger a rule each time that the content is edited, and then verify the relevant data of your content to decide if you need to do either of these:

- no more need to postpone the deletion of content "later on", so just DELETE the scheduled execution of the Rule to delete content.
- (re-)schedule the execution of the Rule to delete content.

PS: from revision 1 of your question, I understand it is about D7 ...

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.Vriens. You are wright. I did it by means of Rules module. I'll check the link you gave.

Comment: I've been far from this issue for a long time. And still do not have a solution. I did try to give the "scheduler" a variable that is an addition to the calculed remaining time and the new value to add. But it does not take variables.